# checkout_onepage_controller_success_action is not working

Tags: php, magento2

I want to save order data in custom Table After order success.
app/code/VendorName/Checkout/etc/event.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
        <observer name="MyObserver" instance="VendorName\Checkout\Observer\MyObserver"  />
    </event> 
</config>
```

app/code/VendorName/Checkout/Observer/MyObserver.php

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\Checkout\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class MyObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
      public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

     $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
     echo $orderId = $orderIds[0]; exit;

    }

}
```

Event is not trigger success.phtml is redirected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `event.xml` file name should be `events.xml`. After renaming file check again

If still the problem, put your events file to

```
app/code/VendorName/Checkout/etc/frontend/events.xml
```

Confirm if the plugin installed by executing

```
php bin/magento module:status
```

If the module is not listed, execute

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: What you have did, have you renamed the file event.xml to events.xml ?

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working fine now. I have changed to events.xml.